# Search for Variable Usage In SSIS tasks

Tags: ssis

As what seems to be some sort of penance for sins in a prior life, I have been tasked with maintaining some SSIS packages. (NO! NO BADMOUTHING SSIS!! BAD PROGRAMMMER! NO DOUGHNUT!).
Anyhoo, I many of the packages have variables, defined in an outer container, which are used in multiple inner containers, in script tasks. 
What I want to do, is find out all the places in a package a variable being used; in other words, search for instances of variable usage in all tasks of a package. This would be a huge help, but I cannot for the life of me find out how this can be done in BIDS. 
(this is SSIS/BIDS 2008)
Thanks for any help,

YS

Comment: Feel free to badmouth SSIS. It is very powereful for complex ETL, but maintainable it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct the SSIS packages are xml files.

So one way I can think of is to  could open the file with your XML-editor of choice and just to a simple search/find on the variable name.

Hope that helps!

Comment: meh. Though this is better than nothing, slogging through the xml is pretty painful too. I'm hoping for a more VS-oriented solution. 
Thanks for replying.

Comment: @yoni.s: There is none to the best of my knowledge. I had to whip up a simple xml parser in c# to achieve this. If you know c# and can read/understand xml you are unfamiliar with it's 2-3 hours job.

Comment: Hey @zespri, if you've got the c# for this published anywhere, it'd be great to link to it. I'm thinking I'll have to write something extremely similar.